# Как правильно задать blur для тени?

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать `div` c тенью цвета `#000000`, 40% прозрачности и 20px размытием (`blur`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем за основу:

```
box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];
```

Получаем:

```
<div style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)">
```

`#000000` нужно записать в `rgba` секции, где последним параметром задается `opacity`